# Simplexml issue Can't get Null from empty attribute

Tags: php, null, simplexml

Hi Guys Hope you can Help:

I am trying to read the xml that is part of a sports scheduling program.

I have Below a Sample of the XML I am reading. So far using Simpmle XML I have been able to read all attributes of a game correctly. However in The example you can see that homescore and awayscore will only show as "" until a score is entered. This is great because I want to put a simple if statement saying if score is null echo "-". This way the viewer knows they are yet to play.

```
<Fixture Id="404" FixtureName="Round 4" ResourceId="4" PlayingAreaName="Court C" VenueId="2" VenueName="Adelaide Indoor Sports Centre" MapLink="" HomeTeamId="212" HomeTeam="THE SHINERS" HomeTeamScore="29" HomeTeamForfeit="False" AwayTeamId="203" AwayTeam="SANDBAR WARRIORS" AwayTeamScore="8" AwayTeamForfeit="False" Duration="40" Umpires="" CrossLeague="False" DivisionName="Division 1" CalendarColour="FFFF00" ResourceOrder="3" DateTime="13/03/2012 21:20"/>
<Fixture Id="406" FixtureName="Round 4" ResourceId="5" PlayingAreaName="Court D" VenueId="2" VenueName="Adelaide Indoor Sports Centre" MapLink="" HomeTeamId="210" HomeTeam="WE THOUGHT IT WAS A DISCO" HomeTeamScore="" HomeTeamForfeit="False" AwayTeamId="206" AwayTeam="AVERAGE JOE'S" AwayTeamScore="" AwayTeamForfeit="False" Duration="40" Umpires="" CrossLeague="False" DivisionName="" CalendarColour="FFFF00" ResourceOrder="4" DateTime="13/03/2012 21:20"/>
```

But The "" (empty attribute) always returns zero. Any Tips? I'm relatively new to php

Comment: PHP doesn't have strong typing. Therefore sometimes things like this happen. You can use gettype() function to check what type is your variable is. [Here is the link to gettype documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the empty() function.

```
if (empty($fixture['HomeTeamScore'])) {
    echo "-";
}
```

[PHP: empty - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Thought that was what you wanted. I don't quite understand your question then, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to distinguish between `""` and `"0"`. Because PHP tries as hard as it can to guess what types you're comparing, statements like `$foo == 0` and `$foo == ''` won't do this, as it will guess that you want to compare numbers, and treat `""` as `0`.

There are a couple of ways to deal with this:

- use the `===` operator instead of `==` (or `!==` instead of `!=`) (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
- check the length of the string using `strlen` to see if it is empty
- check the type of the variable using `is_int`, `is_string`, etc - *this one probably won't work if you've grabbed the values out of SimpleXML, which returns its own types*

Since you're using SimpleXML, I would imagine the code would look something like:

```
if ( (string)$fixture['HomeTeamScore'] === '' )
{
    echo '-';
}
else
{
    echo (string)$fixture['HomeTeamScore'];
}
```